# I can not connect to aws eu-central-1 by using aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I can not connect to eu-central-1 using aws.

I am trying:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-central-1
```

Return is suggesting that there is no eu-central-1 at all.

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
aws: error: argument --region: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

us-west-2                                | fips-us-gov-west-1                      
cn-north-1                               | us-east-1                               
us-west-1                                | ap-northeast-1                          
ap-southeast-1                           | sa-east-1                               
us-gov-west-1                            | ap-southeast-2                          
eu-west-1
```

I gave my user admin permissions in IAM management console.
When I try

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region eu-west-1
```

I get:

```
{
    "Reservations": []
}
```

Specifications of my instance has: Availability zone
eu-central-1b (I even tried to add b just in case, same thing)

I gave Access Key and Secret Access Key to aws configure. Should I give something else in region instead of eu-central-1?

Comment: Show the output from running `aws --version`. I'm guessing you need to update your CLI version.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your version of the AWS CLI. It's too old to recognize the eu-central-1 region.

Use `aws --version` to display the current version of the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu and the packaged version was too old. I had to install `awscli` with pip to get a version which knows of `eu-central-1`.

This version works for me:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/1.11.144 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-123-generic botocore/1.7.2
```